# Get a spread result from azure search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I need some help with making Azure Search Service giving me the right result set.

Let's say I run a query with a filter, and the result set is larger than 1000 records, then the Search Service will return a link for the next page. This limitation is understandable, but also causes a problem.

For example, I will query our users index with a filter like this:

$filter=coinsWon gt 5000 and coinsWon lt 50000

This query might return 2 000 000 records. From those 2 000 000 records, I just need 25 records. I can't use Top=25 because that will only give me the 25 records closest to 5000 or closest to 50000.

My need is to get a record set with 25 records selected from those 2 000 000 records that is spread out from 5000 to 50000 coinsWon. For example records with coinsWon equals 5 000, 7 000, 9 100, 11 000, 12 250, 15 000, 15 500, 17 000, 20 000, 21 000, 23 000, 24 500, 27 000, 35 000, 40 000, 42 000, 45 000, 47 000, 48 000, 50 000.

Since the service is limiting the result set to 1000 records, I am not able to develop this functionality in our APIs either. And even if Microsoft removed the 1000 records limit, it would still be immensely stupid to return 2 000 000 records to our API and then perform a spread selection from the record set. It makes much more sense to be able to ask the search service for a spread record set:

$filter=coinsWon between 5000-50000 spread$top=25

Does anyone have a clever idea on how to solve this? :)

Comment: To clarify, are you asking for a random distribution of search results at specific intervals of coinsWon?

Comment: Also, why do you need to do this? Can you describe your overall scenario?

Comment: Hi, yes, a random distribution of search results, but not necessarily specific intervals. As long as it is near evenly spread it works fine. This will be used in a game we are working on, ranking lists specific for user.

I've asked Microsoft support for a suggestion as well, waiting to hear back from them. It would be great if we could use the search service for this scenario, but if not I'll fix it with a redis instance and some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Azure Search does not support returning a random distribution of search results. You can add a suggestion [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) if you think this is a feature Azure Search should support.